# How to solve Xcode dyld_shared_cache_extract_dylib failed with iOS 13.2

Tags: ios, xcode

This fix no longer works with iOS 13.2 for when XCode says

> dyld_shared_cache_extract_dylib failed

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m3jST08imY0

Anybody know what an updated fix is?

Comment: I tried working magic on this but it's a doozy. I posted an answer that I later deleted since it didn't work for me, if you have success with it lmk and I'll repost. For now I'm uploading builds to appcenter (formerly hockey app) then downloading on my devices - it's what it is.